# Profile view count not updating last few days, since new profiles were launched

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, profile-page

The last 3 or 4 days, I continuously see same view count for [my profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3326275/jquery-php-magento-com?tab=profile) visitors.

It constantly says 2359 since last 3 or 4 days. And by considering [my rank in this week *(28)*](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/week/stackoverflow/2015-04-19/3326275#3326275), I believe many people might have visited my profile. Even you all visit my profile, it will still remain 2359 only.

Is this a bug?

[image: My Profile Screenshot]

Comment: it seems OP is right , i have visited his profile and it is still 2359 ... should have increased .. and i m 100% sure tht  i have not visited his profile till today

Comment: @EladStern , Really ? It was a bug i guess , I see profile 3,4 times a day and this time I didnt get an updated value. I dont need to get more views For Your Info. And please stop being `rude`!

Comment: Sigh, don't take things so seriously. I had a prominent *wink* at the end of my statement which should have emphasized a light-hearted nature.

Comment: @EladStern , if its like that , then sorry :) . Dont mind.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is fixed and the fix is being rolled out right now.

Visiting the activity page did work, just the completely brand new profile didn't :(